# Need to select rows where a person's separate sessions overlap

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to extract all rows where information has been incorrectly inserted into the database. Essentially a person cannot be in 2 Sessions at once, so I want to get all rows where 2 sessions overlap.

I have the following code that I've built on from previous questions asked but cannot seem to get just the overlapping Sessions data.

```
SELECT
       a.[abc_id]
      ,a.[abc_person]
      ,a.[abc_date]
      ,a.[abc_duration]



FROM [flx_Session] a
JOIN [flx_Session] b on a.abc_date <= (DATEADD(MINUTE, b.abc_duration, b.abc_date))
    AND (DATEADD(MINUTE, a.abc_duration, a.abc_date)) >= b.abc_date
    AND a.abc_person != b.abc_person
```

Comment: Just to clarify, if Mr Smith starts a sessionid at 09.30 with a duration of 60 minutes (ends at 10.30), he cannot also be in a sessionid that started at 10.00 with a duration of 45 minutes (or any length of time for that matter). These are the rows I want to extract. many thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you have looks correct at first glance except for the last part of the join clause.

Try this:

```
select
    a.[abc_id]
  , a.[abc_person]
  , a.[abc_date]
  , a.[abc_duration]
from [cedar].[dbo].[flx_Session] a
  join [cedar].[dbo].[flx_Session] b 
    on a.abc_date < dateadd(minute, b.abc_duration-1, b.abc_date)
   and dateadd(minute, a.abc_duration-1, a.abc_date) > b.abc_date
   and a.abc_person = b.abc_person
   and a.abc_id != b.abc_id
```

Comment: That's pretty much fixed it.

Comment: One minor addition is that I'm getting 2 records overlap when the minutes are being rounded up / down by consecutive sessions, so I want to omit these. i.e. Session 1 is 60 minutes starts at 10:00 - 11:00; Session 2 is 60 minutes starts at 10:59 - 11:59. basically these should be allowed as the rounding has caused the overlap. What I was thinking is to a) EITHER reduce Session 1 duration by 1 minute OR move back Session 1 start-time by 1 minute
b) INCREASE Session 2 start-time by 1 minute

Comment: JOIN [CEDAR].[dbo].[flx_learnerSupportSession] b on a.lss_date <= DATEADD(MINUTE, b.lss_duration, b.lss_date)
    AND DATEADD(MINUTE, a.lss_duration - 1), a.lss_date) >= DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, b.lss_date)

Comment: Doesn't quite work as it removes the Session 1 part of the overlapping session but not Session 2 from results. Keeps all other problem sessions in results. Any ideas??